# Thousands of network messages in systemlog

Tags: networking, syslog

Our Ubuntu server kernel log is being spammed by the following messages:

```
Feb  5 12:08:32 Server kernel: [2071471.605255] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eno1 SRC=192.168.48.2 DST=192.168.48.139 LEN=312 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43291 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=55778 WINDOW=501 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

There are about 50 messages each second.
It looks as if some debugging has been activated, but I'm not aware of any such thing. It generates GB size logs each day.
What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a standard firewall log message. Run `iptables-save` or `nft list ruleset` and grep for any rules mentioning 'BANDWIDTH_OUT:' (which is the "log prefix" parameter).

GitHub Code Search suggests that rules with this specific prefix are added [by Webmin](https://github.com/webmin/webmin/blob/3cb936d7c85f0e3bcca4593f9f69642b5f1c3701/bandwidth/bandwidth-lib.pl#L243-L287). (It sets the rules' log level to 'debug', which is usually ignored by most syslog-daemon configurations... but since it inserts the rules at the top, yeah, they do trigger for *every single packet.* I have no idea why it would do that.)

Comment: It was indeed triggered by the webmin network monitoring. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be _so_ much nicer (and less resource-intensive) for Webmin to get the same information from conntrack, like ulogd2 does, but this whole lot of code is 17 years old and barely touched since, so I guess that's why.